# How to do two for loops in a single python loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, naivebayes

I don't mean to shortening this:

```
for x in data1:
    for y in data2:
        *lines*
```

but to do this:

```
for x in data1:
    *lines*

for y in data2:
    *lines*
```

into a single loop like this (x is row from data1 and y is row from data2 only):

```
for x,y in data1,data2:
    *lines*
```

is this possible? I want to fit and then predict Naive Bayes data in a single loop:

```
# group data by prodi
for no, dfx_prodi in dfx.groupby('prodi'):
    # implement naive bayes fit data
    bnb.fit(dfx_prodi[var], dfx_prodi['daftar_kembali'])

for no, dfy_prodi in dfy.groupby('prodi'):
    # implement naive bayes predict data
    y_pred = bnb.predict(dfy_prodi[var])
```

It works, but the result seem fishy, are there any way to do it in one loop while keeping the groupby?

Comment: You can try a while loop. i = 0 while i < len(data1) and i < len(data2)

Comment: try `for x,y in zip(data1, data2):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood something, you can just use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) function, for example as

```
for x,y in zip(x_list,y_list):
    print(x,y)
```

In your case this should be something like

```
for (no, dfx_prodi), (no, dfy_prodi) in zip(dfx.groupby('prodi'), dfy.groupby('prodi')):
    # implement naive bayes fit data
    bnb.fit(dfx_prodi[var], dfx_prodi['daftar_kembali'])
    y_pred = bnb.predict(dfy_prodi[var])
```

Comment: It works, and the result is not fishy (not YES only), thank you!

Answer (score 3):

IF the two lists (iterables) data1 and data2 have the same length, you can do:

```
for x, y in zip(data1, data2):
    do_something(x, y)
```

zip creates tuples (x, y) from 2 or more iterables. If data1 and data2 don't have the same length, you  might look at `zip_longest` in the `itertools` standard library (it adds `None` values for missing items).